# Visual C++ 2008: omp.h not found? /openMP is set

Tags: visual-c++, openmp

I've enabled openMP using the project settings, but when I do #include  I get an error the file doesn't exist. I'm using Visual Studio stadnard edition, not Express... what else is missing? Every page I find simply says to turn it on in project settings and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

omp.h and vcomp.lib is only available in VS Pro editions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the directory containing the file `omp.h` to the list of directory search paths? Go to "tools - options - projects and solutions - VC++ Directories", then "show directories for" "include files". Add the path in here.

Comment: I've no idea where omp.h is... it's a standard header I thought so the standard include paths should cover it? Apparently not, the linker also complains it can't find VCOMP.lib

Comment: Yes, I seem to have it in the standard include paths - better do a search of your machine to see where you have it, and if that path is included in the search paths.

Answer (score 0):

The [solution](http://kenny-tm.xanga.com/651048063/parallel-programming-using-openmp-with-visual-c-2008-express/) for Visual Studio 2008 Express to develop OpenMP on Windows also works with the Standard Edition.

Basically you need to install the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E6E1C3DF-A74F-4207-8586-711EBE331CDC&displaylang=en) for OpenMP to get the libraries and headers. In my case I had to install the patch [KB974479](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5687) too, but that may not be the case if one enables Microsoft Update for VS2008 (which I forgot to enable for all Microsoft products right after installing Windows).